# What is an alternate solution if I can't overload a function?

Tags: vb.net, primitive-types, type-safety

What I am doing is generic and has been done a thousand times, but I can't figure out how other programmers do this.

I am working with the Law of Sines to return an angle of A.  There are two combinations, for instance:

1. Return Angle A given (side b, side a, angle B)
2. Return Angle A given (side c, side a, angle C)

----Note: All together there would be six, two for each angle)----

I can't overload the functions because the signatures are not unique.  The parameters and return type are primitive type Double.

The use of Aliases works for reading the code but does nothing to resolve my issue.

One approach I thought of was to create a structure for each side and angle; however, I don't want to create any more complexity than needed.

Another solution could be using a strategy design pattern?

I'm a hobbyist programmer (still beginner level);I'm trying to build some good programming practices.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If each of your methods are going to do the same thing, why do you need to overload them?

Comment: @Timiz0r The arguments are logically different but the methods have the same signature

Comment: me232 is on spot.  I did initially create one function to use for all angles, however, when I used it in a different context within a higher abstracted function, the test for the other triangle solutions failed.  In other words, the final triangle(s) solutions returned the correct data, just in a different order...as Hand-E-Food has mentioned- transposition .

Comment: Wouldn't both of the other solutions require the law of cosines at some point, unless I'm forgetting something. Getting back to convention, it should be the responsibility of the programmer to use the method correctly. The method doesn't need to know which side or angle is which; the programmer should know that while using the method. Of course, good code documentation is a must for libraries.

Comment: Your right Timiz0r, good documentation is a must, and yes, the law of cosines would be used at some point.  With the law of cosines I can label a function "GetSide_A", "GetSide_B", and so forth.  The names are different so there is no problem with function clashing.  I'm beginning to think I need to redesign what I have.  I am trying to make self-documenting code (it's been a long time since I had trig) and the guy I am building the library for is less versed in VB.Net than I am.  I will try to see if I can post a simple diagram of my intentions.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a different naming convention and a boolean parameter:

```
Public Function GetAngle(adjacentSide As Double, oppositeSide As Double, knownAngle As Double, Optional knownAngleCorrespondsToAdjacentSide As Boolean = True) As Double
```

When called, you now know if it's:

```
GetAngle(c, a, C)           'or
GetAngle(b, a, B)           'or
GetAngle(b, a, C, False)    'or
GetAngle(c, a, B, False)
```

That said, since A, B, & C are arbitrary labels:

```
     a                   b                   c    
__________          __________          __________
\B      C/          \C      A/          \A      B/
 \      /            \      /            \      /
c \    / b    =>    a \    / c    =>     b\    / a
   \ A/                \ B/                \ C/
    \/                  \/                  \/
```

you either need two functions (Private would work fine) or just handle your calculations internally base on the boolean:

```
Public Function GetAngle(adjacentSide As Double, oppositeSide As Double, knownAngle As Double, Optional knownAngleCorrespondsToAdjacentSide As Boolean = True) As Double
    If knownAngleCorrespondsToAdjacentSide Then
        'Calculate one way
        ' or call private method
    Else
        'Calculate the other
        ' or call the other private method
    End If

    Return calculatedAngle
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best thing to do would be to use one method. Your method's signature would look something like this:

```
Public Function GetAngle(commonSide As Double, commonAngle As Double, otherSide As Double) As Double
```

Your method would return the other, target angle of the triangle. I couldn't really think of better parameter names, though.

Comment: Thanks for parameter name naming convention, they clarify the intent of my one generic function ("GetAngle") that my wrapper functions (Angle_A,Angle_B,Angle_C) share. I'm passing this library off to someone else, so I'm trying to keep the function intent simple. However, I'm still in need of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

ASCII art time!

```
     a
__________
\B      C/
 \      /
c \    / b
   \ A/
    \/
```

Given that `b` and `B` can be transposed with `c` and `C`, there are only three formulas you need:

> A = ƒ(a, b, B), transpose `(b, B)` for `(c, C)` if necessary.
>   A = ƒ(a, b, C), transpose `(b, C)` for `(c, B)` if necessary.
>   A = ƒ(b, c, B), transpose `(B)` for `(C)` if necessary.

Given theses all have two lengths and an angle, you'll need three different method names:

```
GetAngleFromOppositeLineAndLooseAngle(oppositeLine , adjacentLine , looseAngle)
GetAngleFromOppositeLineAndJointAngle(oppositeLine , adjacentLine , jointAngle)
GetAngleFromAdjacentLines            (adjacentLine1, adjacentLine2, looseAngle)
```

Otherwise, yes you'll have to pass a structure and discern the missing information.  Use `Nullable(Of Double)` or `Double.NaN` to pass unknown values.